# Visual studio is not picking up changes to Razor files during debugging session

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I was able to edit Razor views (cshmtl), css and JS files while during a debugging session. When i make a change to a razor file, I was able to see the changes after refreshing the page.

Right now, I cant. What is the problem here? Why cant visual studio pick up changes?

Comment: I assume that something is wrong with your debugging configuration. you might need to ensure about **Configuration Properties** of the solution you are working on it. sometimes it happens when a web project is in release mode

Comment: Are you sure the razor views are not cached/pre-compiled?